# Replacing NAs in probability vector

Tags: r

What is a good way to get rid of  `NA`  values in a probability vector in R? I am doing some sampling and sometimes there are  `NA`  values in the probability vector because there are no occurrences of a particular value in a population. The code below illustrates the issue:

```
population <- c("A", "B", "B")
probs <- prop.table(table(population))
action <- c("A", "C", "D")
test <- sample(action,1,prob=c(probs[1], probs[2], probs[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want to specify the probability of each element of `action` using the probability of the corresponding element in `population`. You can do this by character indexing the `probs` vector, specifically, indexing `probs` with `population`:

```
set.seed(1L);
population <- c('A','B','B');
probs <- prop.table(table(population));
action <- c('A','C','D');
test <- sample(action,1L,prob=probs[population]);
test;
## [1] "C"
```

Your code is failing because `probs` only has two elements; `probs[3]` returns NA. Also note that `probs[1:3]` is a more concise factoring of `c(probs[1],probs[2],probs[3])`.

Comment: `1L` is an integer literal, whereas `1` would be a double literal. It's not essential to differentiate between these two storage types in most cases, but I like to use the appropriate type in all cases, I suppose for correctness, consistency, and possible performance benefits (i.e. reducing the need for coercions). In this case, the `size` argument of `sample()` should be an integer. It only adds one more character to the numeric literal, so I don't think it's a big deal.